# Not able to start WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 in linux box

Tags: wso2

I have started wso2 4.0.3 in my local and tested It is working fine.

But same version I have installed in linux box,server not started it is showing    below   error.  I used this command to start: nohup sh wso2server.sh

> ERROR - DatabaseUtil Database Error - Table "UM_DIALECT" not found;
>   SQL statement:
>       SELECT COUNT(UM_ID) FROM UM_DIALECT WHERE UM_TENANT_ID=? [42102-140]
>       org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "UM_DIALECT" not found; SQL statement:
>       SELECT COUNT(UM_ID) FROM UM_DIALECT WHERE UM_TENANT_ID=? [42102-140]

Answer (score 2):

It should be working fine if you are using fresh binary pack (zip). Are you using different  type of database other than H2? (H2 is the default database shipped with the binary pack)
if you are getting this error again, please start sever with -Dsetup option.

Ex : wso2server.sh -Dsetup

Thanks,
Chamara Silva

Comment: wso2server.sh -Dsetup is also useful if you've managed to corrupt your H2 database and just want WSO2 to recreate a new instance of it from scratch

Answer (score 0):

It happen because your WSO2 ESB is missing previous data from the previous database.
You can find your carbon database in

> $wso2dir\repository\database\WSO2CARBON_DB.h2.db

Maybe there are files that missing or can't be copied to your linux environment (not only your carbon database but also other configuration files). Based on @ChamaraS's answer, i also suggest you to using fresh binary pack or create a backup pack with your custom configuration.

ps: i am just curious if you used Filezilla to transfer those files (face same problem here)